# Why does my Verilog testbench never stop?

Tags: verilog

Professor gives the code below, and I have to figure out why it will never stop.

```
module tb_problem1();

reg a, b, c, d, e;
wire x;
reg [4:0] ins;

problem1 dut(a, b, c, d, e, x);

initial begin
    ins = 0;
    while(ins < 32) begin
        {a, b, c, d, e} = ins;
        #20;
        ins = ins + 1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Is that because we need to do `ins = ins+1'b1;` ?

Answer (score 5):

A 5-bit unsigned value supports the range 0 to 31. Adding 1 to 31 will drop the msb and return 0. Therefore the value of 32 will never be reached.

Try making `ins` a 6-bit value.

Comment: is that okay if I make   ins<31;  ?

Comment: Then the condition for `a, b, c, d, e` all being 1 will not happen. A do-while would work with `ins<31`